# Presenting hierarchical data with different conditions using joins in SQL Server 2012

Tags: t-sql

I have two tables. In one table my raw data and in other table the relationships as below

```
Declare @Emp table(EmpId int,EmpName Varchar(100),CITY VARCHAR(100),Designation Varchar(100),ReportingManager Int)
INSERT INTO @Emp
VALUES(1,'Ram','Hyderabad','TL',6)
,(2,'Laxman','Hyderabad','TL',9)
,(3,'Suresh','Bangalore','Officer',6)
,(4,'Rajesh','Bangalore','Officer',9)
,(5,'Lokesh','Delhi','TL',6)
,(6,'Venkatesh','Mumbai','Manager',6)
,(7,'Subbu','Patna','Officer',9)
,(8,'Ravi','Hyderabad','Officer',9)
,(9,'Sai','Hyderabad','Manager',9)
,(10,'Satish','Hyderabad','Officer',6)

DECLARE @EmpRelation TABLE(EmpRelationShipID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,ReportingTo INT,EmpID INT)
INSERT INTO @EmpRelation
VALUES(1,6)
,(2,9)
,(3,1)
,(4,5)
,(5,6)
,(7,2)
,(8,5)
,(10,1)
```

- Here the ReportingManager Column in @Emp table indicates that If Emp
  reports TL, then the TL's ManagerName.
- Here ReportingTo Column in @EmpRelation indicates to whom he is
  reporting.(TL or Manager).
- Officers reports to TLs and TLs reports to Managers.

To get the result the have the below query which is working good

```
    SELECT E.EmpId
    ,E.EmpName
    ,CASE 
        WHEN E.EmpId = E.ReportingManager
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END AS IsManager

    ,CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS (
                SELECT NULL
                FROM @EmpRelation ER
                WHERE ER.ReportingTo = E.EmpId
                )
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END AS HasSubordinates
    ,CASE WHEN E.EmpId != ReportingManager THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsSubordinate
FROM @Emp E;
```

I want the query to be written using the joins instead of using the tables in Case statement.

I tried the below query. Please suggest any correction in terms of performance keeping view the future data size.

```
    SELECT E.EmpId
    ,E.EmpName
    ,CASE 
        WHEN E.EmpId = E.ReportingManager
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END AS IsManager
        ,CASE WHEN HasSubordinate>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END HasSubordinates 
    ,CASE WHEN E.EmpId != ReportingManager THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsSubordinate
FROM @Emp E
LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*)HasSubordinate,ReportingTo Reporting FROM @EmpRelation ER GROUP BY ReportingTo)X ON X.Reporting=E.EmpID
```

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: First, don't use `count` when you mean `exists`. Getting a precise count just so you can compare it to zero doesn't improve performance. You can replace the subqueries with outer joins and grouping, but I don't think it would be clearer or provide better performance. Dare I ask, what is the motivation behind changing the query? What are the _specific_ requirements for the change, e.g. is `cross apply` not allowed?

Comment: I don't need count. I want Exists only.